# How to make scroll behavior smooth when click on button?

Tags: html, button, scroll, onclick

I am using a button to make the user scroll to particular div but the scrolling is so quick it's like instant I want it to be smooth here is the div id and the button code.

```html
<div id="movenow"></div>


<a href="#movenow"> <button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg mydriveBtn" style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;" type="button" data-uid="D0SIeWVycWcyQ05jTG8">GO</button> </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this javascript it works for me. look here for reference http://jsfiddle.net/9SDLw/

```js
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```